# Is there a way to change where a reference member of std::pair is pointing?

Tags: c++

So once an `std::pair` with at least one reference variable has been initialized, for example like this:

```
int a = 53;
int b = 42;
std::pair<int, int&> foo(33, a);
```

Is there a way to change where the reference variable is pointing?

Assignment:

```
foo = std::make_pair(33, std::ref(b));
```

and swapping:

```
std::pair<int, int&> bar(33, b);
foo.swap(bar);
```

appear to just move the new contents to `a` and leave second member of `foo` pointing where it was before (`a`), therefore not doing what I'm trying to achieve here. I am aware that references cannot be rebound as
[answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728233/why-are-references-not-reseatable-in-c), but this isn't what I am trying to do here. What I'm trying to do is make a new pair and assign its contents to an existing one which technically isn't the same thing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not use a reference_wrapper instead?

Comment: I'd recommend using `std::reference_wrapper<T>` as the type instead of `int&`

Comment: "which technically isn't the same thing" yes it is.... what do you think the `std::pair` assignment operator does under the hood?

Comment: *"which technically isn't the same thing"* -- false. It doesn't matter if the reference is inside a pair or not. Attempting to assign a new reference to an existing reference *is* an attempt to rebind the reference. You just threw on an extra layer of obfuscation than most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You shouldn't rebind references...

...but you kinda can. Trying to assign a reference is impossible, but you can achieve the same effect

```
new (&foo) std::pair<int, int&>(33, b);
```

will destroy the old pair<sup>†</sup> and construct a new pair referencing `b`. You are correct, a pair with a reference member isn't the same as a plain reference.

There are many [rules](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.life#8), caveats and ways you can make a mistake here. Just accept that references aren't meant for reassignment.

<sub>†But not call the destructor, which is fine here. Placement new is less error prone in C++20 due to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62163774/4832499).</sub>

Comment: Pre-C++20 the resulting reference can't be used without `std::launder`ing it every time. And I my own code I'd probably call the destructor, for extra clarity.

Answer (score 5):

References always work the same way in C++.

```
int a;
int &b=a;
```

`b` will always be a reference to `a`, until `b` goes out of scope and gets destroyed.

References in `std::pair`s, or anywhere else, work the same way. Once they are bound, they will always refer to the same object they were bound to. Assigning to a reference will always assign to the referenced object.

It also doesn't matter what the reference is to, to an `int`, to a `char`, or to any other objects. References always work the same way, in this respect.

Answer (score 0):

> What I'm trying to do is make a new pair and assign its contents to an existing one which technically isn't the same thing.

You can do that. The assignment operator of the pair assigns each member. When a reference member is assigned, the referred object is assigned. If you want this assignment to rebind the member of that pair, then you want what you know is not possible.